# Swift3 - Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'FileAttributeType'

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, swift3.2

I am trying to check FileAttributeType.
Here is my logic to compare:-

```
let attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath: "/Users/AUSER/Desktop/Downloads")
            print(attributes)

            if (attributes[FileAttributeKey.type] as AnyObject? == FileAttributeType.typeSymbolicLink ){
                print("YESSS \(attributes[FileAttributeKey.type])")
            }
```

Error->
 **Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'FileAttributeType'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (big) mistake is that you cast a very specific type

> `static let type: FileAttributeKey`
>
> The corresponding value is an **String** object

to a very unspecific type `AnyObject`. `AnyObject` cannot be compared.

---

Cast the type to `String` and compare with the rawValue of the `FileAttributeType`

```
if attributes[FileAttributeKey.type] as? String == FileAttributeType.typeSymbolicLink.rawValue {
```

Side note: It's highly recommended to use always URLs rather than string paths and get the file attributes directly from the `URL`

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/AUSER/Desktop/Downloads")
if let resourceValues = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileResourceTypeKey]),
    resourceValues.fileResourceType! == .symbolicLink {
    print("YESSS \(resourceValues.fileResourceType!.rawValue)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian for clarification